# javax.ws.rs.core.response entity does not entertain @JsonProperty

Tags: json, rest

I have created a Rest method like

```
@GET
@Path("/test/output")
public Response getOffers(){
   Test response = new Test();
   return Response.status(200).entity(response).build();
}

class Test{
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    String firstName;
}
```

Now when I see the response I see the response as below

```
{ "firstName":"Ritesh"}
```

Whereas I wanted the output as

```
{"first_name":"Ritesh"}
```

Could anybody please help me understand why Response class is not entertaining annotation?

Comment: It is based on variables, getters setters.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: `public class Test {
  String first_name;

public String getFirst_name() {
 return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
 this.first_name = first_name;
}
  
  
}` try this you will get the desired output but it is not recommended. I hope you are well aware of java naming conventions.

Comment: Sumesh...you have changed the variable name. I want the variable name as per java coding style but the output can vary. For example we can use @JsonProperty in case of Jackson to accomplish the same.

Comment: Nevermind...I have figure out the solution.

Comment: Are you converted your object to JSON before sending the response

Comment: Yes...it is being converted to JSON but not by me but by Jersey

Comment: Do you fixed...?

Comment: yeah....it is working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the solution by using

```
@XmlElement(name="first_name")
```

Instead of using

```
@JsonProperty("first_name")
```